# How do I mirror cells based on one cell being today's date with several adjacent cells

Tags: google-sheets, calendar, match, formula, vlookup

I have made a dynamic calendar in google sheets that will highlight todays date and several cells using conditional formatting. I would like to create on a new sheet in the same workbook a "Today View" in which it searches the workbook for the highlighted cells that are denoting "today" and then mirror these cells on the Today View sheet.

Im trying VLOOKUP or MATCH, in combination with OFFSET, to attempt to locate todays date no matter the sheet, then display cells the X number of rows below the date, with no success. Im not sure how else to accomplish this

Edit: Here is a link to a sample spreadsheet. The first sheet is the "Today View" I would like, the second sheet is a sample of the calendar.

I would like the cells in the range A2:G8 to mirror the cells that are highlighted in green on the calendar sheet, regardless of which sheet is being sourced. The intended goal would be each day this range is updated with the cells that correspond to the new cells from the calendar, displaying the tasks that I have planned for that day without needing to go to the sheet with the specific date

```html
<iframe src="https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/e/2PACX-1vQJ8b8aDP-HgctIlthRkwfF7EO43Es9v8m68QztdkAyl_jBYj_ZGO_QFxALDvSzQ7ftEavx-wZXauCW/pubhtml?widget=true&amp;headers=false"  width="100%" height="500"></iframe>
```

Comment: share a copy of your sheet with example of desired result

Comment: I have updated the question to include an embedded sample workbook

Answer (score 1):

see:

```
=ARRAYFORMULA(QUERY({INDIRECT("Sheet3!"&
 ADDRESS(MAX(IF(REGEXMATCH(B4:D14&"", B1&""), ROW(B4:D14), 0))+1+N("< offset start"), 
         MAX(IF(REGEXMATCH(B4:D14&"", B1&""), COLUMN(B4:D14), 0)))&":"&
 ADDRESS(MAX(IF(REGEXMATCH(B4:D14&"", B1&""), ROW(B4:D14), 0))+4+N("< offset end"), 
         MAX(IF(REGEXMATCH(B4:D14&"", B1&""), COLUMN(B4:D14), 0))))}, 
 "where Col1 is not null"))
```

[image]

### [demo sheet](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/14lcNvYAqx8klPJm-sIL3A9opdvJH-v11ddtS0pZHv18/edit#gid=1241538643)

Comment: Thanks for this feedback! I will try this solution, from the demo you provided it seems like this should work, the only question remains for me is will this solution work across multiple sheets in the same workbook? Each monthly calendar I have set up is on a separate sheet